# Эффективная сортировка

Tags: python

Начинаю изучать Python самостоятельно, решаю задачу:

Требуется написать программу, определяющую, какие клавиши сломаются в процессе заданного варианта эксплуатации клавиатуры.

> Входные данные
>
> Первая строка входных данных содержит целое число n (1≤n≤100) —
> количество клавиш на клавиатуре. Вторая строка содержит n целых чисел
> — c1,c2,…,cn, где ci(1≤ci≤100000) — количество нажатий, выдерживаемых
> i-ой клавишей. Третья строка содержит целое число k (1≤k≤100000) —
> общее количество нажатий клавиш, и последняя строка содержит k целых
> чисел pj(1≤pj≤n) — последовательность нажатых клавиш.
>
> Выходные данные
>
> Необходимо вывести n строк, содержащих информацию об исправности
> клавиш. Если i-ая клавиша сломалась, то i-ая строка должна содержать
> слово “yes” (без кавычек), если же клавиша работоспособна — слово
> “no”.
>
> Примеры
>
> Ввод
>
> ```
> 5
> 1 50 3 4 3
> 16
> 1 2 3 4 5 1 3 3 4 5 5 5 5 5 4 5
> ```
>
> Вывод
>
> ```
> yes
> no
> no
> no
> yes
> ```

Написала программу, но в программе сдачи пишет, что ответ неверный. Хотя в Python Shell всё работает.

```
n = int(input()) 
c = list(map(int, input().split()[:n]))
k = int(input())
p = list(map(int, input().split()[:k])) 
cnt = [0] * (n+1) 
press = list(range(1, n+1))
for el in p: 
    cnt[el] += 1
cnt.remove(0)
for i in range(n):
    if cnt[i] > c[i]:
        print('no')
    else:
        print('yes')
```

Comment: Если запустить ваш код, то он с входными данными даст результат наоборот, т.е. поменяйте местами вывод в условии, т.к. для `cnt[i] > c[i]` нужно вывести `yes`. Кст, код неплохой, но можно обойтись без создания лишнего элемента нужно только индекс уменьшать `cnt[el-1] += 1`, и, лучше, давайте полноценные названия переменным, например не `c`, а например `max_num_pressed`, тогда и код станет более читаемым

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь, учту обязательно всё.

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста сами ответ :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 n = int(input()) 
max_num_pressed = list(map(int, input().split()[:n])) 
k = int(input()) 
p = list(map(int, input().split()[:k])) 
cnt = [0] * (n+1)
for el in p:
    cnt[el-1] += 1
for i in range(n):
    if cnt[i] > max_num_pressed[i]:
        print('no')
    else:
        print('yes')
```

Вот мой код с исправлениями, еще раз спасибо за помощь!